# React leaflet map not updating data / rerending when data changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet to make a map of the counties in each state, but it only shows one state at a time. Ideally, it should work so that users select the state of interest and then the map changes to only show that state. I have a geojson that contains the boundaries for the counties of all 50 states and I'm filtering it to only show the counties that match the currently selected state. However, the filter isn't working to rerender the map. The thing is, the data array does update. I have checked that it shows the correct newly filtered json with the correct state code, but the map isn't changing even though the data field of the  element has changed. The center of the map changes when the new state is selected (which only worked after I added the flyToMap function at the end), but I can't get the data to update. It stays at the data from the original state (Rhode Island)

Here is the code for the full Map element:

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "../../styles/Map.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import WealthChart from "./WealthChart";

function WealthMap(props) {
  const [wealthCounty, setWealthCounty] = useState(props.currState);
  const [wealthData, setWealthData] = useState({});
  
  const styles = {
    height: "30vh",
    width: "30%",
    margin: "0 auto",
  };

  const stateStyles = {
    fillColor: "red",
    color: "gray",
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    weight: 1.5,
  };

  console.log("in wealth map", props.currCounties);

  /**
   * preform api request to ACS 2021 5yr estimates S1903 table to get median household income
   * and margins of error by race/ethnicity
   */
  function getCountyWealthData(county, state) {
    console.log(`count ${county}, state ${state}`);
    // api call
  }

  /**
   * on click, get the county fips code, make api request, and set data as that data to pass to map
   */
  const onWealthCountyClick = (event) => {
    const countyName = event.target.feature.properties.NAME;
    setWealthCounty(countyName);

    const countyFIPS = event.target.feature.properties.COUNTYFP;
    getCountyWealthData(countyFIPS, props.stateFIPS);
  };

  const onEachWealthCounty = (state, layer) => {
    layer.on({
      click: onWealthCountyClick,
    });
  };


  // Function to move the map to the center of the markers after the map is loaded with new data
  function FlyMapTo(props) {
    const map = useMap();

    useEffect(() => {
      map.flyTo(props.center, props.zoom);
    });

    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer style={styles} center={props.currCenter} zoom={8}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&copy; <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a>"
          url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <GeoJSON
          style={stateStyles}
          data={props.currCounties}
          onEachFeature={onEachWealthCounty}
        />
        <FlyMapTo center={props.currCenter} zoom={8} />
      </MapContainer>
      <h3>{wealthCounty}!!</h3>
      <WealthChart data={wealthData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default WealthMap;
```

I know the issue is that the map element is only built once at the beginning, but how can I get it to rerender every time props.currCounties (its data) changes?

Answer (score 1):

The [React Leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#props) state that the props of child components are immutable:

> By default these props should be treated as immutable, only the props
> explicitely documented as mutable in this page will affect the Leaflet
> element when changed.

The [GeoJSON API](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#geojson) states that the `data` property is not mutable, so that explains why the `<GeoJSON>` object doesn't update (even though the underlying data does).

You could add a `key` property to the `GeoJSON` object as follows to trigger updates when the data changes:

```
<GeoJSON
 key={JSON.stringify(props.currCounties)}
 style={stateStyles}
 data={props.currCounties}
 onEachFeature={onEachWealthCounty}
/>
```

When the data (`props.currCounties`) is updated, the value of `JSON.stringify(props.currCounties)` will also change, which will mean the value of `key` changes and therefore force a rerender of the map.

There's a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-example-ctngmq?file=Map.tsx,index.tsx) showing this in action. When the map loads initially, it will render a GeoJSON rectangle object. If you click the **"Update"** button above the map, it will update the underlying data and will re-render as a triangle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I had a similar problem where the map wasn't updating after any change to the centre property

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answer.
I had a similar problem where the map wasn't updating after any change to the centre property. And like Ian pointed out this was due to the fact that the props of child components are immutable. adding the key prop solved the problem.

```
<MapContainer
  key={center[0].toString()}
  className="w-full, h-[40vh]"
  center={center}
  zoom={4}
  scrollWheelZoom={false}
>
  <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
  <Marker position={center}>
  </Marker>
</MapContainer>
```